# PostGIS 3: no spatial operator found for 'st_equals': opfamily 36658 type 36545

Tags: postgresql, postgis

After upgrading to Postgres 12 and PostGIS 3 from 11 and 2.5 respectively, now I'm getting this error when using `ST_Equals` on a geometry column with a GiST index. There was a function with a similar error message caused by a GiST index for `ST_Covers` [which turned out to be a bug](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344408/st-covers-fails-on-geography-column-with-gist-index-postgis-3-0).

I'm trying to jump through the (many) hoops to submit a bug report on PostGIS, but I thought I'd seek feedback on this first, in case it isn't a bug or someone knows otherwise?

Reproduction code, assuming postgis is installed on the `public` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."geopoints" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "geopoint" "public"."geometry",
  CONSTRAINT "geopoints_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
;

CREATE INDEX "index" ON "public"."geopoints" USING gist (
  "geopoint"
);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "public".geopoints g1, geopoints g2 WHERE "public".ST_Equals(g1.geopoint, g2.geopoint)
```

Error reported is `no spatial operator found for 'st_equals': opfamily 36658 type 36545`. **Removing the index, the query runs fine**

PostGIS version: `POSTGIS="3.0.1 3.0.1" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"`

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

Edit, added answers to comment:

```
SELECT a.amopstrategy, a.amoppurpose, o.oprname, f.opfname
FROM pg_amop AS a
   JOIN pg_opfamily AS f ON a.amopfamily = f.oid
   JOIN pg_operator AS o ON a.amopopr = o.oid
WHERE f.oid = 36658;

1   s   <<  gist_geometry_ops_2d
2   s   &<  gist_geometry_ops_2d
3   s   &&  gist_geometry_ops_2d
4   s   &>  gist_geometry_ops_2d
5   s   >>  gist_geometry_ops_2d
6   s   ~=  gist_geometry_ops_2d
7   s   ~   gist_geometry_ops_2d
8   s   @   gist_geometry_ops_2d
9   s   &<| gist_geometry_ops_2d
10  s   <<| gist_geometry_ops_2d
11  s   |>> gist_geometry_ops_2d
12  s   |&> gist_geometry_ops_2d
13  o   <-> gist_geometry_ops_2d
14  o   <#> gist_geometry_ops_2d
```

and

```
SELECT typname, typnamespace::regnamespace,
       typinput::regproc, typoutput::regproc
FROM pg_type WHERE oid = 36545;

geometry    core_system core_system.geometry_in core_system.geometry_out
```

Edit 2:

```
SELECT a.oid AS amop_oid, a.amopstrategy, a.amoppurpose, o.oid AS opr_oid, o.oprname FROM pg_amop AS a JOIN pg_operator AS o ON a.amopopr = o.oid WHERE a.amopfamily = 36658 AND a.amoplefttype = 36545 AND a.amoprighttype = 36545;

36660   1   s   36644   <<
36661   2   s   36646   &<
36662   3   s   36631   &&
36663   4   s   36653   &>
36664   5   s   36643   >>
36665   6   s   36633   ~=
36666   7   s   36640   ~
36667   8   s   36641   @
36668   9   s   36651   &<|
36669   10  s   36649   <<|
36670   11  s   36648   |>>
36671   12  s   36656   |&>
36672   13  o   36636   <->
36673   14  o   36637   <#>
```

Comment: The odd thing here is that the type `geometry` is in schema `public`, but `st_equals` is in schema `core_system`. Unless there is a typo, something is quite strange here: 1) do you have two PostGIS installations in two different schemas? 2) is `core_system.ST_Equals` not from PostGIS?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo. Technically the extension is in a different schema but I meant to write the script as if in the same schema. Now edited

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, I've updated the question with the output from those queries

Comment: Ok, then what do you get for `SELECT a.oid AS amop_oid, a.amopstrategy, a.amoppurpose, o.oid AS opr_oid, o.oprname FROM pg_amop AS a JOIN pg_operator AS o ON a.amopopr = o.oid WHERE a.amopfamily = 36658 AND a.amoplefttype = 36545 AND a.amoprighttype = 36545;`?

Comment: At any rate, so far I see nothing odd. Could you try adding `system_core` to your `search_path` and see if that makes a difference? If yes, it is a PostGIS bug and should be reported. If not, it is still unclear if that is a software bug, data corruption or a pilot error (not correctly installed PostGIS).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Results for the other query added to the question. I have seen that the new PG12 database doesn't have the core_system in the search path. I've added this and the query works! Are you saying this is a bug because of this?

Comment: Yes, this is a PostGIS bug then. Please report it with a short reproducible test case. But first, upgrade to the latest release of PostGIS 3. I have seen several bugs fixed that have to do with `search_path`.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, will send a bug report. I'm on 3.0.1, do you mean 3.1.0-alpha1?

Comment: That's the most recent release of version 3, so your are good. Thanks for the contribution!